# Which NoSql for visualization extensive app

Tags: database, elasticsearch, visualization, data-visualization, nosql

I am about to work on a app that will be showing a lot of visualizations. It is an data read-only application, there will be negligible write operations. We have a lot of data(JSON, CSV), depending on the usecase we will  have to filter to a subset and send it to the UI for visualization.

What kind of NoSQL would you recommend and please do specify the reasons?Thanks!

P.S: Some of the devs are recommending ElasticSearch. I am not sure if we should go for a document store or a key-value in the first place.

Comment: What kind of data do you have to store? Do you have a particular use case? I'd say that to not shape your db based on your visualization, but shape it based on your business logic. Chose based on this last one.

Comment: @MarcoCI We will be storing huge amounts of JSON data mostly, we will  have to fetch results filteres based on a parituclar JSON key. There wont be any writes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're visualizing log data, I'd use logstash in combination with elasticsearch and kibana.   There's also commercial ways to protect your data and more coming.  I'm working on k3bana which will visualize data with X3DOM and D3.js.   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used Redis (with Jedis) to store key-value pairs in one case.